# Java Jsoup downloading torrent file

Tags: java, download, jsoup, torrent

I got a problem, I want to connect to this website (https://ww2.yggtorrent.is) to download torrent file. I've made a method to connect to the website by Jsoup who work well but when I try to use it to Download the torrent file, the website return "You must be connected to download file".

Here is my code to connect:

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://ww2.yggtorrent.is/user/login")
            .data("id", "<MyLogin>", "pass", "<MyPassword>")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
```

and here is my code to download file

```
Response resultImageResponse = Jsoup.connect("https://ww2.yggtorrent.is/engine/download_torrent?id=285633").cookies(cookies)
                                    .ignoreContentType(true).execute();

FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("toto.torrent")));
out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());
out.close();
```

I've tested a lot of thing but now I have no clue.

Comment: Probably authentication issues?

Comment: no because I've tested with a wrong password and it return me an error

Comment: But you sure your correct authentication is being passed?

Comment: yes because it return me the HTML code who say "Welcome Back"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you didn't show us in your code is getting cookies from response. I hope you do this correctly because you use them to make second request.

This code looks like yours but with example of how I get the cookies. I also add referer header. It successfully downloads that file for me and utorrent recognizes it correctly:

```
    // logging in
    System.out.println("logging in...");
    Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://ww2.yggtorrent.is/user/login")
            .timeout(10000)
            .data("id", "<MyLogin>", "pass", "<MyPassword>")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();

    // getting cookies from response
    Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
    System.out.println("got cookies: " + cookies);

    // optional verification if logged in
    System.out.println(Jsoup.connect("https://ww2.yggtorrent.is").cookies(cookies).get()
            .select("#panel-btn").first().text());

    // connecting with cookies, it may be useful to provide referer as some servers expect it
    Response resultImageResponse = Jsoup.connect("https://ww2.yggtorrent.is/engine/download_torrent?id=285633")
            .referrer("https://ww2.yggtorrent.is/engine/download_torrent?id=285633")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .execute();

    // saving file
    FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("C:/toto.torrent")));
    out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());
    out.close();
    System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it work perfectly now ! thanks again !